# Weird see-throught effect

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode

I don't know how I did it but I pressed a button that made that meshes will get invisible if there is another one around or behind them. Anyone know which button I need to press or if it is anything to do with the viewport?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably toggled *X-Ray* mode in the object viewport.

You can switch *X-Ray* mode on and off with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd>